# What security concerns can arise from using HTTP Basic-Authentication?

Tags: authentication, http, web-authentication

During an engagement, i have been asked by a client to explain (with the use of one
or more examples) why they must update their website authentication mechanism,
as they are currently using HTTP Basic-Authentication and how it can be dangerous for
the security of a system

Comment: It's your client and you made the recommendation - why did you recommend it?

Comment: @MechMK1 iam not the one who designed the system, i didn't recommend it

Comment: @SteffenUllrich's linked answer answers the main points. I would also the lack of support for 2FA/MFA.

Comment: If I remember correctly basic auth in a web browser has one large disadvantage: it is impossible to log out. The only way to do so it to close the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue in the current scheme: the user passwords may be stored in **clear text** in the backend, if that is the case then this is the "problem" you'll want to fix. Hash them, salt them. The transport is only part of the problem.

Also consider alternatives like **client certificates**.